Add total row to polars dataframe (to a subset of columns)
I have the following code:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'name':      ['CHECK', 'CASH', 'BAR', 'SET'],
    'category1': ['AM', 'EU', 'EU', 'AS'],
    'category2': ['CA', 'FR', 'DE', 'CX'],
    'quantity':  [100, -20, 10, -70],
    'exposure':  [11, -3, 2, 8]
})
FLT_COLS   = ['quantity', 'exposure']
OTHER_COLS = [c for c in df.columns if c not in FLT_COLS]

df_temp = df.select(pl.col(FLT_COLS)).sum()\
            .with_columns(pl.lit('TOTAL').alias(OTHER_COLS[0]))\
            .with_columns([pl.lit('').alias(c) for c in OTHER_COLS[1:]])[df.columns]

pl.concat([df, df_temp])

which gives me the desired output
shape: (5, 5)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ name  ┆ category1 ┆ category2 ┆ quantity ┆ exposure │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ CHECK ┆ AM        ┆ CA        ┆ 100      ┆ 11       │
│ CASH  ┆ EU        ┆ FR        ┆ -20      ┆ -3       │
│ BAR   ┆ EU        ┆ DE        ┆ 10       ┆ 2        │
│ SET   ┆ AS        ┆ CX        ┆ -70      ┆ 8        │
│ TOTAL ┆           ┆           ┆ 20       ┆ 18       │
└───────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

That is, add a row that contains the total sum across a specific list of columns FLT_COLS, labels the other first column TOTAL and then puts "" into the remaining non-summed columns.
Is there a nicer way to add this row? I feel my code looks very clumsy. I also don't like that I have to specify [df.columns] to re-order the columns, as this feels very inefficient.

One thing you can do is df.sum and do the sum of only numeric columns. e.g. df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True). It will put Nan for non-numeric fields that you can replace later.

Is name known, or do you need to deduce it dynamically? i.e. would pl.concat([df, df.sum().fill_null("").with_columns(name=pl.lit("TOTAL"))]) suffice?

@jqurious I'd say this is as close to the proper answer as it could be

@RomanPekar Thank you for the feedback - I wasn't sure if I was oversimplifying things or not.

Not sure if it is answers entirely, but:
The frame-level .sum() will give null for all the String columns:
>>> df.sum()
shape: (1, 5)
┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ name ┆ category1 ┆ category2 ┆ quantity ┆ exposure │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ null ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ 20       ┆ 18       │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

If name is known, you can then fill_null() and concat()
pl.concat([df, df.sum().fill_null("").with_columns(name=pl.lit("TOTAL"))])

shape: (5, 5)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ name  ┆ category1 ┆ category2 ┆ quantity ┆ exposure │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ CHECK ┆ AM        ┆ CA        ┆ 100      ┆ 11       │
│ CASH  ┆ EU        ┆ FR        ┆ -20      ┆ -3       │
│ BAR   ┆ EU        ┆ DE        ┆ 10       ┆ 2        │
│ SET   ┆ AS        ┆ CX        ┆ -70      ┆ 8        │
│ TOTAL ┆           ┆           ┆ 20       ┆ 18       │
└───────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

Or if like the example, it is always the "first column", you could use pl.first() / pl.nth() to add in the TOTAL string.

.nth()
.replace()

pl.concat([
    df,
    df.sum().fill_null("").with_columns(
        pl.nth(0).replace("", "TOTAL")
    )
])


This is probably more clunky overall but it addresses:

The first column that isn't in FLT_COLS
Doesn't use df.columns

pl.concat([
    df,
    df.select(pl.exclude(FLT_COLS)) # pick all columns that aren't FLT_COLS
      .select(
          pl.first() # this is the first column [that isn't in FLT_COLS]
          .first() # this is first row
          .str.replace(r".*","TOTAL")) # uses regex to replace the first value 
                                       # to TOTAL as workaround for dynamic alias
      .hstack( # add columns of sums
          df.select(pl.col(FLT_COLS).sum())
          )
], how='diagonal' # the diagonal makes any extra columns default None 
                  # and orders them by the first df of the list)

If you know the first column overall isn't in FLT_COLS then you can just do
pl.concat([
    df,
    df.select(
          pl.first().first().str.replace(r".*","TOTAL"),
          pl.col(FLT_COLS).sum()
          )
], how='diagonal')



For given DataFrame, if all Numeric columns in FLT_COLS
df = pl.DataFrame({
 'name':      ['CHECK', 'CASH', 'BAR', 'SET'],
 'category1': ['AM', 'EU', 'EU', 'AS'],
 'category2': ['CA', 'FR', 'DE', 'CX'],
 'quantity':  [100, -20, 10, -70],
 'exposure':  [11, -3, 2, 8]    })



this code work:
df_temp = (
    df.select(pl.all())
    .sum()
    .fill_null(pl.lit(""))
    .with_columns(pl.lit("TOTAL").alias(OTHER_COLS[0]))
)
df = pl.concat([df, df_temp])

output:
shape: (5, 5)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ name  ┆ category1 ┆ category2 ┆ quantity ┆ exposure │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ CHECK ┆ AM        ┆ CA        ┆ 100      ┆ 11       │
│ CASH  ┆ EU        ┆ CA        ┆ -20      ┆ -3       │
│ BAR   ┆ EU        ┆ CA        ┆ 10       ┆ 2        │
│ SET   ┆ AS        ┆ CA        ┆ -70      ┆ 8        │
│ TOTAL ┆           ┆           ┆ 20       ┆ 18       │
└───────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘


if DataFrame, is more complex:

    import polars as pl
    import polars.selectors as cs
    
    df = pl.DataFrame({
            "name": ["CHECK", "CASH", "BAR", "SET"],
            "category1": ["AM", "EU", "EU", "AS"],
            "category2": ["CA", "CA", "CA", "CA"],
            "category3": [1, 1, 1, 1],
            "category4": [1.3, 1.123, 1.1233, 4.232],
            "category5": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01"],
            "quantity": [100, -20, 10, -70],
            "exposure": [11, -3, 2, 8]})
    
    df = df.with_columns(pl.col("category5").str.to_date("%Y-%m-%d"))
    FLT_COLS = ["quantity", "exposure"]
    ALL_OTHER_NUMERIC_CS = cs.all() - cs.by_name(FLT_COLS) & cs.numeric()
    TOTAL_COL = "name"
    
    df_temp = (
        df.select(pl.all())
        .sum()
        .fill_null(pl.lit(""))
        .with_columns(
            (ALL_OTHER_NUMERIC_CS).replace_strict(
            old=(ALL_OTHER_NUMERIC_CS),
                new=pl.lit(None),
            ),
            pl.lit("TOTAL").alias(TOTAL_COL),
        )
    )
    df = pl.concat([df, df_temp])

output:
shape: (5, 8)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ name  ┆ category1 ┆ category2 ┆ category3 ┆ category4 ┆ category5  ┆ quantity ┆ exposure │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ i64       ┆ f64       ┆ date       ┆ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪════════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ CHECK ┆ AM        ┆ CA        ┆ 1         ┆ 1.3       ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 100      ┆ 11       │
│ CASH  ┆ EU        ┆ CA        ┆ 1         ┆ 1.123     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ -20      ┆ -3       │
│ BAR   ┆ EU        ┆ CA        ┆ 1         ┆ 1.1233    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 10       ┆ 2        │
│ SET   ┆ AS        ┆ CA        ┆ 1         ┆ 4.232     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ -70      ┆ 8        │
│ TOTAL ┆           ┆           ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null       ┆ 20       ┆ 18       │
└───────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

